'adb help' for 'root' says "restart adbd with root permissions", but 'adb root' says "adbd cannot run as root in production builds"
Can't make sense of two 'messages':
.\adb root
adbd cannot run as root in production builds

another one
.\adb --help
root               restart adbd with root permissions

seems unrelated to one another, only to me I suppose.
Why?

Why does "adb root" do nothing?

If you execute adb root, adb connects to the selected Android device and sends the command to restart the adbd server running on the Android device and, in the process of restarting, keep root permissions (not drop root permissions as is usually done for security reasons).
By "production builds", adb is referring to the build type of the attached Android device, not the adb tool itself. The adb help page shows this command because it cannot know what type of Android devices you use with adb.
Per Google, adb root is only for ROM development (compiling Android yourself, building a development firmware/ROM).
Common Android phones and tablets you buy always use a production build.

When would the android devices' adbd need be restarted?

@patrickciancioni The restart is necessary because adbd has dropped root permissions - this is the standard behavior for security reasons. To regain root permissions (and then not drop them) a restart is necessary.
